# Does Mail log errors into a console or text file?

Tags: logs, email

Does Mail log errors into a console or text file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to /Library/Scripts/Mail Scripts/Turn On Logging.scpt and Run that.
Otherwise, go here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004101603285984

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
/var/log/mail.log
```

most easily viewed with /Applications/Utilities/Console.app

Comment: Looked there already, didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apple have provided an [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW8-SW1) to a logger database. Apple use the datbase in Mail

The messages are then viewable using the Console.app

Choose All Messages in the lefthand sidebar
Filter on Mail

e.g.
[image: example console.app grab]